# Find all integer solutions of equality

Tags: diophantine-equations

Find all integer solutions of equation $$x^3+(x+1)^3+...+(x+7)^3=y^3$$ I've solved it by opening brackets and consideration of signs but I think there is simpler way of solving it .

Comment: $$y^3=\sum_{r=1}^{x+7}r^3-\sum_{r=1}^{x-1}r^3$$

$$=\frac{\{(x+7)(x+8)\}^2-\{(x-1)x\}^2}4$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee How did you get that?

Comment: @Kugelblitz, $$\sum_{r=n}^mf(r)=\sum_{r=1}^mf(r)-\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}f(r)$$ provided all the sums converge

Comment: @labbhattacharjee , I don't sure that this formula  correct for negative x .

Comment: @AntonyTito, The formula in my first comment holds for $x-1\ge0$

Comment: Note that this seems to be hard, just the case :$x^3+(x+1)^3=y^3$ is not easy (particular case of LFT) which the best we can do is transorme it to $4u^3-v^3=3$ which needs to work in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]4]$, your equation goes in the same direction because it can be simplified to $(x+4)(x^2+8x+28)=49y'^3$ which suggest the same thing because after some tests of divisibility we can reduce it to the same problem

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Right...slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$P(x)=x^3+(x+1)^3+(x+2)^3+(x+3)^3+(x+4)^3+(x+5)^3+(x+6)^3+(x+7)^3$$
so
$$P(-x-7)=-P(x)$$

on the other hand we can 
$$P(x)=8x^3+84x^2+420x+784$$
if $x\ge 0$,we have
$$(2x+7)^3=8x^3+84x^2+294x+343<P(x)<8x^3+120x^2+600x+1000=(2x+10)^3$$
so we have
$$(2x+7)<y<2x+10$$
so 
$$P(x)=(2x+8)^3\Longrightarrow -12x^2+36x+272=0$$
this equation no integer roots,

simaler we have
$$P(x)-(2x+9)^3=-24x^2-66x+55=0$$
also have no integer roots.

Now we have prove $x\ge 0 $ or $x\le -7$ this equation have no integer roots

But if $-6\le x\le 1$, we can easy to find when
$x=-2\Longrightarrow P(-2)=216=6^3$

$x=-3\Longrightarrow P(-3)=64=4^3$

$x=-4,P(-4)=-64=(-4)^3$

$x=-5,P(-5)=216^3=(-6)^3$